# "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Timeout processing request (#10001: Internal Error"

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout

I have integrate my paypal account with my magento ecommerce website but when trying to checkout using paypal I am getting the error "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Timeout processing request (#10001: Internal Error"

Comment: 10001 is a very vague error. See here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#directpayment-errors-and-warnings and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43259/paypal-sandbox-error-10001-timeout-processing-request

Comment: versione of magento and php?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a specific payment model configuration issue. Better to contact [Paypal technical team](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/) to help you on it.